# What happens to the souls of the dead in Age of Sigmar?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy, age-of-sigmar

What happens to the souls of the dead in Age of Sigmar?

We know that the bravest of heroes often gets taken by Sigmar and formed into Stormcast eternals.

But what about the rest?

Are they either Om Nom Nom Nom by the chaos gods, or do Nagash take them to his realm to be his eternal slaves?

Comment: This may be of interest to you: https://www.tga.community/forums/topic/9197-what-exactly-happens-to-souls-in-the-mortal-realms/ And it's apparently not the bravest of souls who Sigmar  has forged into Stormcast eternals but Sigmar worshippers who die fighting Chaos in some way and call out to him at the end.